# SQL count on a created column

Tags: sql, count

The following query calculates the distance of users based on geocoordinates. It returns 4 results for people within 1 miles. How can I count the result and return it?

```
select  ((ACOS(SIN(40.7643030* PI() / 180) * 
                         SIN(users.lat * PI() / 180) + 
                         COS(40.7643030* PI() / 180) * 
                         COS(users.lat * PI() / 180) * 
                         COS((-73.9730040- users.lon) * PI() / 180)) * 
                         180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515)         
                         AS `distance` FROM users HAVING distance < 1
```

I tried to add 'COUNT(*) AS count' after distance but it returns no results.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select  ((ACOS(SIN(40.7643030* PI() / 180) * 
                         SIN(users.lat * PI() / 180) + 
                         COS(40.7643030* PI() / 180) * 
                         COS(users.lat * PI() / 180) * 
                         COS((-73.9730040- users.lon) * PI() / 180)) * 
                         180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515)         
                         AS `distance`
      FROM users
      HAVING distance < 1
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks. You forgot to add 'AS' at the end.

Comment: 'AS' is optional but i do agree that it is more readable with it.

Comment: @Joe . . . I always use `as` for column aliases and never use `as` for table aliases.  The reason I used it for columns is because the absence or presence of a comma can make a big difference in meaning in the column list, if you do not have an `as`.